# How can I prevent Ubuntu One from displaying the same notification over and over?

Tags: ubuntu-one, notification

Ubuntu One is displaying notifications about synchronising the same file(s) over and over and over again, although the file(s) ha(s/ve) not been changed.
I see this notification every time I start the system or resume from standby, and even while running the session the notification appears irregularly, but often.

the text of the notification is:

English singular:

> '%(filename)s' and %(other_files)d other file is being uploaded to
>   your personal cloud.

English plural:

> '%(filename)s' and %(other_files)d other files are being uploaded to
>   your personal cloud.

Current German[0]:

> »%(filename)s« und %(other_files)d andere Datei werden in Ihren
>   persönlichen Online-Speicher hochgeladen.

(see [here](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/ubuntuone-client/+pots/ubuntuone-client/de/+translate).)

**So what can I do to get rid off these useless notifications?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it seems to be solved:

One of the folders I share via Ubuntu One, is the pictures folder in the user directory. Inside this pictures folders, there was a hidden folder called .trash-info or .trashinfo. Inside this folder were two sub-folders, called "info" and "files". the files folder contained the file, which seemed to be synchronized on and on. 
*(I think the .trash-info folder was created by moving some pictures in the trash in shotwell.)*

So I deleted the .trash-info folder. But what happened? It re-appeared instantly! 
I had to delete the .trash-info folder several times on my local computer and in the Ubuntu One webinterface before it finally really disappeared.

From that on, I got no further useless notifications. :-)